# How do I find all the command blocks on a world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Someone on my friend's realm set up a constantly active repeating command block that does "/say Hello! How are you?" and it spams the chat so fast and makes everyone lag really bad, and we can't figure out how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

So, unfortunately this is a rather hard problem to solve. Since on realms, there aren't any external commands or tools you can use. One solution would be to download the world to your computer and use a program like McEdit to find and delete the command block. You could also attempt to find it from in-game. If you are the only player online, the block has to be in the spawn chunks  (approximately 100×100 block area around where you first spawn in) or within the server render distance around you  (also approximately 100x 100 around the player) I would suggest going into spectator mode (/gamemode 3) so that you can no- clip through the terrain.